# How to disable form fields and buttons until a Python subprocess has terminated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, subprocess

I'm a JavaScript/jQuery newbie and need some help with it. In a Django application, I have a single HTML page that contains two forms. When clicking the submit button of the first form, a Python subprocess gets started by the respective Django view. The fields of the first form are for passing parameters to this subprocess. The second form doesn't contain any fields. Its only purpose is to stop the same subprocess when its submit button is clicked.

The entire form submission process happens on the server side. I want to know how to accomplish the following behavior using jQuery:

1. When the HTML page is loaded for the first time, enable all form
   fields and buttons except for the *stop subprocess* button (since
   there is nothing to stop yet)
2. When the *start subprocess* button is clicked, the form's fields and the button itself should be disabled until the subprocess has finished. At the same time, the *stop subprocess* button should be
   enabled.
3. When the *stop subprocess* button is clicked, disable it again until the subprocess has really finished. When the subprocess has finished, go back to step 1.

I know in general how to use jQuery to disable form elements. My problem rather is how make jQuery aware of the status of my subprocess.

Here is the relevant code of the Django views:

```
def process_main_page_forms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['form-type'] == u'webpage-crawler-form':
            template_context = _crawl_webpage(request)

        elif request.POST['form-type'] == u'stop-crawler-form':
            template_context = _stop_crawler(request)
    else:
        template_context = {
            'webpage_crawler_form': WebPageCrawlerForm(),
            'stop_crawler_form': StopCrawlerForm()}

    return render(request, 'main.html', template_context)

def _crawl_webpage(request):
    webpage_crawler_form = WebPageCrawlerForm(request.POST)

    if webpage_crawler_form.is_valid():
        url_to_crawl = webpage_crawler_form.cleaned_data['url_to_crawl']
        maximum_pages_to_crawl = webpage_crawler_form.cleaned_data['maximum_pages_to_crawl']

        program = 'python manage.py crawlwebpages' + ' -n ' + str(maximum_pages_to_crawl) + ' ' + url_to_crawl
        p = subprocess.Popen(program.split())

    template_context = {
        'webpage_crawler_form': webpage_crawler_form,
        'stop_crawler_form': StopCrawlerForm()}

    return template_context

def _stop_crawler(request):
    stop_crawler_form = StopCrawlerForm(request.POST)

    if stop_crawler_form.is_valid():
        with open('scrapy_crawler_process.pid', 'rb') as pidfile:
            process_id = int(pidfile.read().strip())

        # These are the essential lines
        os.kill(process_id, signal.SIGTERM)
        while True:
            try:
                time.sleep(10)
                os.kill(process_id, 0)
            except OSError:
                break
        print 'Crawler process terminated!'

    template_context = {
        'webpage_crawler_form': WebPageCrawlerForm(),
        'stop_crawler_form': stop_crawler_form}

    return template_context
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you just looking for info on how to disable form elements with jquery, or do you need help with the overall idea?

Comment: @noisewaterphd: I know how to disable form elements with jQuery in general. My problem rather is how to make jQuery aware of the status of my subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider firing off the subprocess as an Ajax request to the django view, when you fire the Ajax request, also call your JS method to disable all of the elements.

When the view finishes the processing it will return a response to the Javascript that made the Ajax call. When the javascript receives this response, re-enable all of the form elements.

This will allow for you to also do some error/messaging to the client about process results through the Ajax response from Django.

I hope I have understood your situation properly.

Comment: Yes, you do. :) Your suggestions sound reasonable. Can you maybe give me some general pseudo-code on how to fire a Python subprocess using an Ajax request?

Comment: Ajax requests can be treated just like any other request, and you simply need a view on the backend to respond to it.

Comment: This will block a server thread until that process completes, won't it? You'd need an asynchronous server to avoid blocking.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you could set up jQuery something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#startButton').bind('click', startProcess());
});

var startProcess() = function {
  $('#startButton').unbind('click');
  .ajax({
    url: '',
    data: {},
    dataType: '',
    type: '',
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#stopButton').bind('click', stopProcess());
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#stopButton').unbind('click');             
    },
    error: function(data) {
      // Handle error
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      $('#startButton').bind('click', startProcess());
    },
};

var stopProcess() = function {
  $('#stopButton').unbind('click');

  // Use AJAX to tell django to stop processing

  $('#startButton').bind('click', startProcess());
};
```

You could have Django respond with a success = True, which will in turn trigger the success function.

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json

def json_response(message):
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dict(success=True, message=message)))
```

edit: I haven't tested this yet, and you also have to fill in the details in the AJAX request, but I think it might help.